# Possible to filter dsquery group?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scripting, dsquery

I am trying to output the members of an AD group in an easy to read format with the following:

`dsquery group -name "<AD GROUP NAME>" | dsget group -members -expand | dsget user -samid -fn -ln`

If I just do `dsquery group -name "<AD GROUP NAME>" | dsget group -members -expand` I can see some of the accounts have `CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals` - how do I exclude those from the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following at the end of your commando.

|find /v "CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals"

Comment: Of course! the command I actually used: dsquery group -name "<AD GROUP NAME>" -limit 5000 | dsget group -members | find "OU=User Environment" | dsget user -samid -fn -ln